# Trying to count numbers of topics under a forum board

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Here is what I currently have:

```
@Model.TPGForumTopicQuery.Select(m => m.closed != true && m.deleted != true)
.Where(m => m.TPGForumBoardID == item.boardID).Count()
```

This returns an odd error:

```
An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request.
Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
```

If I remove the .Select it works without error and counts all of the topics under the forum board.  But the topics can be marked 'closed' or 'active' and I need to omit those in the count.

The above code is within a `@foreach loop`.  So `item.boardID` is talking about the Forum Board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do the filter in the `Select`. Do it in the `Where`:

```
@Model.TPGForumTopicQuery.Where(m => m.TPGForumBoardID == item.boardID && m.closed != true && m.deleted != true).Count()
```

**A bit of optimization:**

Rather than `m.closed != true`, do `!m.closed`

```
@Model.TPGForumTopicQuery.Where(m => m.TPGForumBoardID == item.boardID && !m.closed && !m.deleted).Count()
```

And rather than get the `Count` after the `Where`-clause, you can pass in the where-clause to the `Count()`:

```
@Model.TPGForumTopicQuery.Count(m => m.TPGForumBoardID == item.boardID && !m.closed && !m.deleted)
```